# Go gin response middleware

Tags: go, go-gin

I need to manipulate response data in a middleware function. Assume I have product handlers and customer handlers. Product handler returns a list of products and customer returns a list of customers. In the middleware function, I want to convert these responses into ApiResponse struct.

```
type ApiResponse struct{
    Data interface{}
    Status ApiStatus{}
}

func someMiddleware(c *gin.Context){
   //before handlers
   c.Next()
   //I need to access response and manipulate it
   // apiResponse := ApiResponse{}
   // apiResponse.Data = returnedData
   // apiResponse.Status = ApiStatus{}

}
```

I don't want to fill ApiResponse in all handlerFunctions.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit too late, but anyway.

The easiest way is usually to use `Get` and `Set` methods of `gin.Context` to pass data between your middleware and your handlers.

But if you really need to intercept responses, see my answer about [logging response in gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38501325/how-to-log-response-body-in-gin/3854855). The only difference is what you do with intercepted response, but everything said there about intercepting it stays true.